# Bootstrap loading before jquery rails app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-masonry

Hello Guys using bootstrap and masonry on a rails, i have this problem, http://www.bdtesting.pw/  when i hit refresh the page it first show the images in a single column , after that load nice as masonry grid, looks like bootstrap is loading first and not sure how fix it.
This are my js code :
http://pastebin.com/DDPkZ1mk

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Try changing the order inside your application.js per the [docs](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks): `//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks`. And bootstrapjs doesn't appear to be loading at all (or at least not that I could find)

Comment: i did and does not fix, i think is the price of use masonry, maybe i need to find a nice way to preload the images maybe using a spinner.